# OSX HUD Panel Fully transparent

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a mac app with a base HUD window. I want to make the window completely transparent and have NSViews on top with content. If I change the alphas of the panel then the content will be transparent and I don't want that. What is the easiest way to make the background invisible. Thanks.

Edit 1:
I have an NSWindowController to controller the initial window, then it transitions to a View Controller. But I think the initial window is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure a `NSWindow` with a fully transparent background, you have to set `NSColor.clearColor()` as background color and additionally set the `opaque` flag to `false`. (Otherwise you'll get drawing glitches).

The following code renders a window, that can host visible controls, but is otherwise invisible:
[image: Transparent NSWindow]

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
        self.window?.opaque = false
        self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        let existingStyleMask = self.window!.styleMask
        self.window?.styleMask = existingStyleMask|NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that code to my NSWindowController but it did not change the background. Thanks For the fast reply!

Comment: Where exactly did you add it? Probably window is still nil? Another option would be that your window uses some style mask that is not compatible with one of the above flags. Can you try a non-HUD, non-Panel window?

Comment: Great that fixed it! Side not, can I set it so that you can click through the app?

Comment: You could try ignoresMouseEvents = true for the window, but then you'll have to handle clicks on your controls with an event monitor or sth like that :/ I currently can't think of a better solution.

Comment: The last time I played with this sort of thing, clicks went through the clearColor areas automatically.  That was with a borderless window, though; perhaps the fact that you're doing this with a HUD window is getting in the way.  If you could switch to using a borderless window, it might facilitate things, since perhaps Cocoa has more of an expectation that a borderless window would have transparent regions.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got the clicks to work, but a new error has come up with the webview and the transparency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546362/osx-webview-drawing-bug